# Refresh the access token for Google Calendar API

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

Currently, I am using https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php this api but token expire after 3-4 hours, how to auto refresh access token for Google Calendar API

Current Code is:

```
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/google-calender/credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client ->setApprovalPrompt ('force');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    $tokenPath =__DIR__ . '/google-calender/token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the new access token on your client after requesting a new one.

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
        }
```

my [sample](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)

Comment: client->getAccessToken() return this value:

{"access_token":"ya29.GltbBgaJz6eYMpLwdqrwe2MmT-yu3sVt539OnKpu1kiy-tNtJ14rSEmopHxKW7_vJ5uZ2zHPKofki4msLFaXtWxqrveKRrS-GD7Th4taKteX1Q9A4f9UYVzDih-4","expires_in":3600,"scope":"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/calendar","token_type":"Bearer","created":1542802697}

access_token is new refresh token?

Comment: No the access token is the access token you use to access the API. Its only valid for an hour (3600)  Refresh tokens dont expire as long as you have it saved some where you will be able to use it to access the users data by requesting a new access token when ever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to never need to worry about the expiration token.
For that you need to create inside GCP a project, then create an oauth, then create a service account:

1- Go to gcp and create a new project, enable calendar api or any api you want to use,after that create OAuth and download a json file form it, then go toService Account just below OAuth and create a service account and download a json key form it. You will use that key to create your authentication.

2- Go to the calendar you want to user with your api and add the email you created in the service account and set the permissions as you like.

From now on, you can use the ooauth json and the service account json to access your calendar and it will not have expiration date. The same method can be used for other services.